# I am creating a Tetris clone on Khanacademy, will I get into trouble?

Tags: legal, tetris

For those don't know, Khanacademy is an education site that also has lessons on simple computer programming and allows you to publish your own games that are made on the website.

Comment: You might want to consult [related questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=tetris+%5Blegal%5D).

Answer (score 0):

If your game is called "Tetris" and/or it uses assets from the original game, then yes you might get in trouble.

If your game is called "Falling Block Extremo" and it uses assets you have permission to use, then no you should't get in trouble.

This is the same of any platform, not just Khanacademy.